# moving data from gridview

Tags: gridview, rows

I am using two gridview including checkboxes.

The value of both gridview is retrived from database.

When selecting checkbox from gridview1 the corresponding row should be moved to gridview2.

How this can be done..

Comment: what's the language, `GridView` is an ASP.NET Control, is this ASP.NET? Please specify everything in your question so you get better help. Or is this a windows application?

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming that this is a web application*

if you just want to move rows from 2 tables, you can easily accomplish this with any javascript framework, and with more code if you don't want to use any javascript framework :)

Let's assume, that you have two `<table>`'s that are generated from the `datagrid`'s

```
<table class="tbl-1">
 <tr>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" /> 
  <td>
  <td>
    My First Row 
  <td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" /> 
  <td>
  <td>
    My Second Row 
  <td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

and let's assume that the second `<table>` is the same but with `class="tbl-2"`

all you need is:

```
$(".tbl-1 input:checkbox").bind("click", function() {
    // let's grab the row and clone it
    var row = $(this).parents("tr").clone();

    //let's append to the tbl-2
    $(".tbl-2").append(row.fadeIn(500));

    // let's fade and delete the row in the tbl-1
    $(this).parents("tr").fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).remove(); });
});
```

[working example in JsBin](http://jsbin.com/exugo4/edit#preview)